# BigQuery - Get percentage of null values in column grouped by another

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

I have a table like

| store_code | country_code | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | FR | 1234567890 |
| 123 | FR | 1234567890 |
| 456 | GB | 1234567890 |
| 789 | GB | 1234567890 |

I would like to get

| pct_null_store_code | country_code |
| --- | --- |
| 0.5 | FR |
| 0.0 | GB |

I know how to do it with a `WHERE` clause as in

```
SELECT SAFE_DIVIDE(COUNTIF(store_code IS NULL), COUNT(1)) as pct_null_store_code
FROM table
WHERE country_code = 'XX'
```

But I would like to only have to exec 1 query and get the results for each `country_code`

Answer (score 2):

One method just uses `avg()`:

```
SELECT country_code, 
       AVG(case when store_code IS NULL then 1.0 else 0 end) as null_ratio
FROM table
GROUP BY country_code;
```

If you want to do the count and divide by the total, then use `COUNTIF()`:

```
SELECT country_code, 
       COUNTIF(store_code IS NULL) * 1.0 / COUNT(*) as null_ratio
FROM table
GROUP BY country_code;
```